# QT Creator, editing keys not working

Tags: qt, qt-creator, redhat

I'm using Qt Creator, from About Qt Creator:

4.1.0
Based on Qt 5.7.0 (GCC 4.9.1 20140922 (Red Hat 4.9.1-10), 64 bit)

Built on Aug 24 2016 14:58:22

From revision 8c80a86266

Enterprise Features: Enabled
Licensee: ##################

I'm using Qt on RedHat:

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 7.2 (Maipo)

I've been using Qt on the same system for over a year, today the IDE suddenly started behaving strangely, I can no longer use the arrow keys with shift depressed to select text, neither can I use the Find feature Ctrl+F.

In any other application on the same system these keys work as expected, but not in Qt Creator.

Its driving me crazy, what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I must have pressed Alt+V and enabled "VIM-style Editing", this caused a world of pain.

https://forum.qt.io/topic/7676/disable-command-and-insert-mode-in-qtcreator-s-texteditor